# Upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 not possible because of a problem with Oracle Java 9

Tags: package-management, upgrade

When the computer tries to upgrade, it says there is an error with Oracle Java 9.

I successfully uninstalled Oracle Java 9.  But when I tried to reinstall it, it gave me this error:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know how to correct this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix mentioned in another question with same error on a different package and upgrade:

Try this simple workaround:

```
sudo apt-get clean        
sudo dpkg --clear-avail    
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it still failed.   Here is what it told me:  download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java9-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is "download failed". Never got downloaded. So I found this for you:

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html

> Update April 2018: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life and its binaries are no longer available to download, so the installer in this article won't work. Use Oracle Java 8 or Java 10 instead.

It isn't there. It won't download. Read that page and go with Java 8 or Java 10.